French movie - violin, gondola type boat
"This movies is most certainly The Violin Player (Le joueur de violon), 1994."
Caught the latter half of this movie on TV perhaps about 6-8 years ago.
It was in French so I could not understand any of the dialog.
However, I distinctly remember this scene from it: at the end there is a man playing a violin and he is on a gondola type boat, slowly floating away under an (arched?) bridge.
Thank you very much!
P.S.: Some other random things I think might be from it: was the guy poor and had to sell his violin? was the guy listening to tape recorder and pretending to play? ...

Was the movie itself old or fairly recent? What did the guy look like? Do you remember anything else (like maybe the song he played?)

It was a modern movie (i.e. not black and white and not from the 80s). Have no recollection of the guy's looks or the song :(  It was very touching despite the lack of understanding of the language.

This movie is most certainly The Violin Player (Le joueur de violon), 1994.
The boat scene can be seen here (3:10)



I have not seen it myself but the man is not pretending to play... he's actually a virtuoso, and for some reasons he decided to put his career on hold to play in the Paris subway.
